# Customize Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Could you please have a look at http://raufthecoder.wordpress.com/2011/08/06/per-site-customization-in-mozilla-firefox/ . It explains how to customize Mozilla Firefox using 'userContent.css'. How can I do it in Internet Explorer ?

Comment: You should probably cut and past your code in.  I'm pretty sure your CSS is wrong. . .

Comment: I don’t see what’s wrong with it. It works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Internet Options->General->Accessibility->Format documents using my style sheet** :

In Internet Explorer (or the Control Panel), select `Internet Options`, then click the `Accessibility` button in the `General` tab. Check the `Format documents using my stylesheet` check-box and click Browse to select a CSS stylesheet of your choosing. (Click OK, OK.)

Now your user-stylesheet will be applied to all websites that you browse, depending on what you put it in.

Comment: I specified img
{
opacity: 0.03;
} in a file and then browsed and selected it. But it DO NOT work

Comment: [Yes it does.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cXsvy.png) It won’t take until you close and re-open the browser, or at least a tab; simply reloading the page isn’t enough. (When testing CSS, I prefer to use something like `* {background:#ff0000;}`; it’s much more noticeable and universally applicable.)